# Which is best FaceNet or dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, image-recognition

I am newbie in face recognition related things... As far i observed dlib's `frontal_face_detector`is widely used to find the faces in an image and after that, to extract face_descriptor vectors which is better for real time face authentication system ?

- [FaceNet by google](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832)
- [dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1 by face_recognition](https://pypi.org/project/face_recognition/)

It looks both working fine.. but in real-time implementation,

- Is there some thing important to understand the performance ?
- Or any comparison checks done on real time / large data sets ?

  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with the natively LR, tinyface dataset, dlib's resnetv1 model failed to extract embeddings for a number of faces from images with high gaussian blur. However, FaceNet was able to vectorize those same poor-quality LR images.